# Typed JS code not finishing before new function called

Tags: javascript, function, typedjs

*Issue:* Typed JS code is not finishing before next function is called.
*Solution:* Add anything to make it wait before executing the next function.
I know there are solutions already posted to this kind of problem but I can't get any of them to work. **This is a last resort.**

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Button</button>
<div>
  <p id="coolArray" onload="myFunction"></p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var typed = new Typed("#coolArray", {
    strings: ["pHolder1", "pHolder2", "pHolder3", "pHolder4", "pHolder5", "pHolder6", "pHolder7", "pHolder8"],
    typeSpeed:  70,
    backSpeed: 70,
    loop: false,
    showCursor: false,
    smartBackspace: false
  });
}
function newFunction() {
  for (i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
    // do smth else
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Edit:* I made it fully functioning from copy, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Looks like [from the docs](https://mattboldt.github.io/typed.js/docs/#typed) there's an `oncomplete` handler in the options you pass to the constructor to run a function when the animation finishes.

Comment: Oh, ty. I really needed this. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the `oncomplete` attribute. took a little digging but I found out how to use it. This was my first time using TypedJS and I didn't know about this attribute, and I still don't know many others, but I hope to get better. Thanks for your help!